# Could alloys be electroplated onto a substrate?

Tags: electroplating

For example, if I want to electroplate stainless steel onto copper, could that work? 
I understand that different ions would need different voltages, but would those lower voltage ions merely make the lower voltage ion be deposited faster, or completely prevent the higher voltage ion from depositing at all?

Comment: Some alloys probably could be electroplated with carefully chosen electrolyte and voltage, but steel... well, I don't think so. How would you electroplate carbon, to begin with?

Comment: So theoretically it would be possible (as long as all the elements have soluble ionic compounds, e.g., not carbon)?

Comment: Yes, it looks theoretically possible . Might turn out impractical, but that's another story.

Comment: If it were easy then it would be a common industrial procedure. There are plenty of times when plating substrates with stainless steel would be really useful. The fact that it isn't done suggests either that it is impossible or very very impractical.